# Foursquare - OAuth Authentication - .Net Sample

Tags: .net, oauth, foursquare

Is there any sample on how to authenticate to Foursquare using Oauth ?

Answer (score 2):

There a very nice workflow summary for how to use OAuth with Foursquare here:
http://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html

Once you get authenticated with OAuth, you can start making foursquare API calls:
http://developer.foursquare.com/docs/overview.html